# Android setInitialScale is not working for mobile pages

Tags: android, webview, zooming

I am creating an application where I have to resize the content of a webview. Everything works fine until I load inside the webView a mobile page. No matter what value I set to `setInitialScale(n)` the content of webView is not resizing. Below is the code I am using:

```
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);  
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.setInitialScale(33);
webView.loadUrl("http://m.jurnalul.ro");
```

Is there any possibility to zoom out or in the content of a WebView that contains a mobile page.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried :

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

switch (metrics.densityDpi) {
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
    break;

case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
    break;

case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.CLOSE);
    break;

default:
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried the code you write it and is still not working. I don't think is possible to resize the content of a web page designed for mobile use. I think that if the page width fits the screen width then the scale option are disabled.

Comment: This solution does not provide for a precise zoom factor.