# Android Webview not rendering correctly on ICS 4.0 +

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a problem with an Android app I am working on.

I loaded a locally stored HTML into a WebView and set:

```
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

It works great, but just not on ICS 4.0+.

Any ideas what to do?

Here are some screenshots to document the error:

[image: Correct layout] [image: Broken layout]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

switch (metrics.densityDpi) {
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
    break;

case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
    break;

case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.CLOSE);
    break;

default:
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
    break;
}
```

[See original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6898641/1581147)

OR Have you tried this?

```
WebView webview1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
webview1.setInitialScale(90);
webview1.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Comment: Thanx for the tip. Unfortunatly it did not make any difference

Comment: @user1787952 I have updated the answer, give this a try. Also, tell me is your problem device specific or just Android version specific?

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks more like a styling issue in your CSS code. Try playing around with the width sizes.

You might want to load a difference css for viewing it on a mobile device.