# WebView, showing blank in ICS

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am loading a local `HTML` document kept in `assets` folder into a `WebView`. It is showing fine in 2.3 devices but, showing blank screen in ICS + devices.

Comment: can you share some code? as that can prove to be helpful to know what exactly may be the reason..your problem statement is clear.

Comment: @SanjayD, This is the code I have used:
gWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.gWebView);
WebSettings webSettings = gWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
gWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using this code

```
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

As per my knowledge flash url do not work in ICS.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work

```
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.loadUrl(url);
weevils.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

Also check that the internet permission in declared in your manifest.xml
And take a look at this thread which is quite similar:
[Android Webview not rendering correctly on ICS 4.0 +](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154268/android-webview-not-rendering-correctly-on-ics-4-0)

Comment: @Manjunath How is it not working. Are you getting errors? Can you copy+paste your logcat.

Comment: It doesn't give error. It works like a champ in 2.3 version. But, shows blank in ICS. I tested on HTC Nexus one(works) and Galaxy Nexus(doesn't work)(It has Jelly Bean).

Answer (score 0):

try adding this code if the above answer does not solve the problem

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

I an not too sure on this though.